# Add filenames to multiple for loops

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a list of file names, like this.

```
file_names = ['file1', 'file2']
```

Also, I have a list of key words I am trying to extract from some files.  So, the list of key words (`list_1`, `list_2`) and the text string that come from `file1` and `file2` are below,

```
## list_1 keywords
list_1 = ['hi', 'hello']

## list_2 keywords
list_2 = ['I', 'am']

## Text strings from file_1 and file_2
big_list = ['hi I am so and so how are you', 'hello hope all goes well by the way I can help you']
```

My function to extract text,

```
def my_func(text_string, key_words):    
    sentences = re.findall(r"([^.]*\.)" ,text_string)  
    for sentence in sentences:
        if all(word in sentence for word in key_words):
            return sentence
```

Now, I am going through multiple lists with two different for loops (as shown below) and with the funciton. After end of each iteration of these multiple for loops, I want to save the file with the filenames from `file_names` list.

```
for a,b in zip(list_1,list_2):
    for item in big_list:
        sentence_1 = my_func(item, a.split(' '))
        sentence_2 = my_func(item, b.split(' '))
        ## Here I would like to add the file name i.e (print(filename))

        print(sentence_1)
        print(sentence_2)
```

I need an output that looks like this,

```
file1 is:
None
file2 is:
None
```

You can ignore `None` in my output now, as my main focus is to iterate though filename list and add them to my output. I would appreciate any help to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the index in Python for loops and use this index to find the file to which the string corresponds. With this you can print out the current file.

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
for a,b in zip(list_1,list_2):
    # idx is the index here
    for idx, item in enumerate(big_list):
        sentence_1 = extract_text(item, a)
        sentence_2 = extract_text(item, b)
        prefix = file_names[idx] + " is: " # Use idx to get the file from the file list
        if sentence_1 is not None:
            print(prefix + sentence_1)
        if sentence_2 is not None:
            print(prefix + sentence_2)
```

**Update:**

If you want to print the results after the iteration you can save temporarily the results in a dictionary and then loop through it:

```
for a,b in zip(list_1,list_2):
    # idx is the index here
    resMap = {}
    for idx, item in enumerate(big_list):
        sentence_1 = extract_text(item, a)
        sentence_2 = extract_text(item, b)
        if sentence_1 is not None:
            resMap[file_names[idx]] = sentence_1
        if sentence_2 is not None:
            resMap[file_names[idx]] = sentence_2
    for k in resMap.keys():
        prefix = k + " is: " # Use idx to get the file from the file list
        print (prefix + resMap[k])
```

Comment: @user9431057 If you need to print the results after the iteration you can store the intermediate results in a map and then print the map out afterwards. See updated answer.